# iOS NUserActivity & CSSearchableItemAttributeSet ratings attribute

Tags: ios, ios-searchapi

I'm using the search api in iOS with `NSUserActivity` and Core Spotlight indexing - I've got it all working fine apart from I can't get the ratings for my item to display on the search results?

I've set my `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` with the type `kUTTypeContent` and have set the rating and ratingDescription attributes, whilst all the other attributes I'm populating are working fine the ratings aren't being shown! Anyone else managed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this on Apple forum:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14386

Apple have to fix this issue. But i notified some applications (Zomato) are showing rating on spotlight search.

CSSearchableItemAttributeSet is not supporting NSAttributedString. In my openion, you can use symbols now.

```
 attributeSet.contentDescription = "Rating: ⭐️⭐️⭐️"
```

Comment: Thanks, don't think I'd want to go down the road of using symbols - but I change the type to Audio then it works!